# Wordpress Heartbeat API minimal interval

Tags: wordpress, heartbeat

What is the minimal interval between pulses in Wordpress Heartbeat API? I am referring to changing default interval, not this other feature allowing to temporary speed pulses for 2,5 minutes.

Is this good idea to lower this interval under 5 seconds?

If there is Heartbeat pulse waiting for response from server, will there be next pulse send even if previous one is not completed? Or it will wait until previous one is completed and then send next one?

Answer (score 0):

Is this good idea to lower this interval under 5 seconds? It depends on your server and how many browser windows are open at once. Of course it won't help your cause if a user leaves a window open idle

Answer (score 0):

I believe the lowest interval available is every 15 seconds.